# Recommended workflow for Redmine + bzr?

Tags: version-control, bug-tracking, bazaar, redmine

I have just set up Redmine on my server with a project that has been under bazaar version control.

Here is the existing workflow:

1. Each developer (including myself) creates a branch from the development trunk.
2. Developer makes changes and commits to their branch
3. I merge developer's branch into trunk

After importing the trunk into Redmine, only the messages associated with commits to the trunk are registered, but messages committed by by developers are not. Thus, for example, if a developer adds 'fixes #2' to the commit message, it does not close issue #2; rather, I have to add 'fixes #2' to the commit that I do after the merge.

Is there something wrong with my workflow, or is there a better way to use Redmine with my current workflow?

Comment: Redmine also has an open issue (I believe) of not refreshing the SCM view until the Repository tab is clicked. Could this have something to do with your issue states?

Comment: @serotonin, no, I have noticed this issue but it is not related to my problem; I can not find any record of changes made to the branches through redmine.

Comment: Which version of Redmine are you working with?

Comment: @serotonin version 1.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **shared repository feature** #2799 may fix your issue.
This feature is still open, but **there is a patch attached** that seems to work (according to comments).

Feature #2799 : Support for Bazaar's shared reposetories (created with init-repo)
http://www.redmine.org/issues/2799

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can not see merged revisions is that, at present, Redmine can not handle them. Sorry I can not give you a more helpful answer.  :o(

See the following for more information:

- [Redmine issue 3559](http://www.redmine.org/issues/3559) — Allow viewing of sub-revision in Bazaar VCS revision history
- [Bazaar merged revisions don't show up](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/17587) (forum thread)